# AngularJS 2 with SQL

Tags: sql, angular

Is it possible to make the database on SQL for our Angular 2 app ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, are you asking if it is possible to connect to a relational database that supports being queried with SQL directly from a front-end app built with Angular 2?

Comment: Why would you think that it would not be possible?

Comment: Yes, its what i mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular is a front end framework.  It typically interacts with a backend web service to fetch and put data.  As such, the backend web service can use any storage medium it desires, and the Angular app won't care.